# Radioactive pollution

Tags: radioactivity

Why doesn't anyone somehow collect radioactive elements from polluted areas like Pripyat in Chernobyl? Should we really wait for thousands years until it stop being radioactive? Maybe there are ways to clean everything up. For example using robots with some "magnet" or vacuum cleaner on board that move across polluted areas and suck in all radionuclides ? Sorry for probably dumb or already asked question, I'm not a physicist.

Comment: Even if the area was cleaned up, new radioactive chemicals are still being produced inside and near the power plant and some of them would naturally be released into the environment. If a costly action to clean up the area is to be done, it is probably best done only after release of radioactive elements is stopped and prevented Partially this is done by the new confinement, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernobyl_New_Safe_Confinement I think a large scale cleanup operation probably won't happen for political/economical reasons - Ukraine has no money and other states do not care that much.

Comment: @JánLalinský Thank you for answer. Yes, this is the sad truth that probably no large scale cleanup will happen.

Comment: How do you intend to only vacuum up the radionuclides vs all the other nuclei?

Comment: @JonCuster I don't know, this is why I asked the question. And , as I understood , the answer is that it is almost impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've answered the question yourself: how do you make this special 'magnet' that selects only radionuclides?  The only practical way do do such a thing would be to pick up *everything* then somehow separate the radioactive stuff, which you could do, for instance, by carefully selecting things by atomic mass in some kind of huge mass-spectrometer.  Doing this on a large scale is ludicrously impractical and, even if it could be done, it would require separating the whole environment into its atomic (or perhaps molecular if you were lucky) constituents.

In other places where such things have happened the approach has often been to remove a layer of topsoil and bury it somewhere, which is less impractical but still extremely destructive.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is definitely impractical, but I can't stand with a thought that once such disaster occurred there are no really effective ways to restore everything back. And the zone around nuclear power plant will probably stand uninhabitable for decades.

Comment: Chemical separation would take care of a big chunk of the problem.  There is no need to have _any_ isotope of cesium or strontium in topsoil, for example. Unfortunately, even a chemistry-based cleanup of one thousand square miles of topsoil and vegetation would be more costly than any nation could afford.

Comment: @M.Laurance: I don't want to say anything controversial, but there's a difference between how much radiation we find politically acceptable and how much is actually bad for us (this is not to say that the area around Chernobyl is safe, but a lot of it is, perhaps, not as dangerous as some people would have you believe).